# Как изменить цвет элемента при нажатии в другой части экрана?

Tags: css

Как изменить цвет элемента при нажатии в другой части экрана?

Например у меня есть блок и он зеленый. При нажатии на другой части экрана, вре данного блока изменить его на красный?

Знаю что :focus нужен. Но как дать условие?

Answer (score 2):

Возможно.

```
<HTML>
<HEAD>
<META http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
<TITLE>Как изменить цвет элемента при нажатии в другой части экрана?</TITLE>
<STYLE>
#t1:focus ~ #t2{background:black;}
</STYLE>
</HEAD>
<BODY>
    <INPUT TYPE='text' ID='t1' />
    <INPUT TYPE='text' ID='t2' />
</BODY>
</HTML>
```

http://jsbin.com/ukahis/17/edit

**НО!** не все тэги HTML поддерживают :focus и работает это только в одном порядке(допустим нельзя снизу вверх обращаться)

Comment: @qpaycm зачем писать теги верхним регистром?)

Comment: Говорится о блочном элементе (вероятнее всего о **div**). Относительно тегов, поддерживающих селектор **focus** в моем ответе информация есть. Своим ответом вы не опровергаете мое высказывание. Прочитайте ответ внимательнее или приведите пример, когда вы сможете изменять цвет фона у блока div без помощи **js**

Comment: @jesus, чтоб видно было ) просто пример другого вопроса готовый на локалке ждал своего часа.

@VenZell, уважаемый, Вы писали:

>> С помощью только стилей сделать это невозможно...

В следующий раз давайте свои формулировки точнее.

Comment: @qpaycm, А вторую часть фразы вы намеренно опускаете? **поскольку селектор применяется только к (тут список селекторов)**

Comment: @VenZell, несмотря на то, что селектор применяется только к... С помощью только стилей сделать это возможно по отношению к тэгам в коих применяется селектор. Другими словами из Вашего ответа я понял, что несмотря на что селектор в тэге есть, это невозможно. Мой пример показывает, как это возможно. Надеюсь теперь мы поняли друг друга?

Comment: @qpaycm, безусловно поняли.

Answer (score 1):

С помощью **только стилей** сделать это невозможно, поскольку селектор применяется только к

```
<a>, <input>, <select> и <textarea>
```

**[Источник](http://htmlbook.ru/css/focus)**

Есть способ сделать это с помощью **javascript**  (атрибут **tabindex** у **div** должен быть обязательно).

**HTML**

```
<div id="mydiv" tabindex="100"></div>
```

**javascript**

```
$("#mydiv").focusin(function() {
  $("#mydiv").css("background","red");
});
$("#mydiv").focusout(function() {
  $("#mydiv").css("background","white");
});
```

**css**

```
#mydiv{
    width : 50px;
    height:50px;
    border : 1px solid red;
}
```

Пример: **[jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/kPbfL/1/)**
**[Источник](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11280379/is-it-possible-to-write-onfocus-lostfocus-handler-for-a-div-using-js-or-jquery)**

Comment: Сделал так: http://jsfiddle.net/RC4Eh/ 

Не работает =/

Answer (score 1):

**navi1893**, у вас не получается, потому что делаете ошибки в синтаксисе. К примеру, вы пишите:

```
 .css({'display' : 'block'});
```

вместо

```
.css('display','block');
```

А вот когда идет группа css-свойств правильно использовать:

```
.css({свойство1: значение1, свойство2: значение2, ...})
```

Пользуйтесь [картой функций](http://jquery.page2page.ru/tags/ifr.html).

Answer (score 0):

Попробовал сделать вариант на **чистом** CSS. Вот что получилось: http://jsfiddle.net/QV4L5/1/

Если нажать на зеленый div, то он останется зеленым. Нажимаем за его пределами - станет красным. Единственный недостаток - нет возможности вернуть div в исходное состояние при клике на него. (Может кто-то подскажет.)

---

**HTML**

```
<div></div> <!-- зеленый div -->
<br /><br /><br /><br />
<a href="javascript:;">sample link</a>
<br /><br /><br /><br />
<button>test</button>
<input />
```

**CSS**

```
div {
    background: green;
    width: 100px; height: 100px;

    animation-name: change-bg;
    -webkit-animation-name: change-bg;

    animation-duration: 1ms;
    -webkit-animation-duration: 1ms;

    animation-fill-mode:forwards;
    -webkit-animation-fill-mode:forwards;

    animation-play-state: paused;
    -webkit-animation-play-state: paused;
}

@keyframes change-bg {
    from { background-color: green; }
    to { background-color : red; }
}

@-webkit-keyframes change-bg {
    from { background-color: green; }
    to { background-color : red; }
}

body:active div, body:focus div
{
    animation-play-state: running;
    -webkit-animation-play-state: running;
}
body:active div:active, body:focus div:focus { 
    animation-fill-mode:none;
    -webkit-animation-fill-mode:none;
    animation-play-state: paused;
    -webkit-animation-play-state: paused;
}
```

---

Работает все это в **Chrome, Firefox**. В IE 10 работает, но срабатывает не на всех элементах. В Opera есть пока проблемы с тем, что анимация проигрывается при загрузке страницы. (Возможно кто-то знает как исправить)